# Tag merge [tag:kitchen] to [tag:kitchens]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, retagging

I see two tags: [kitchen](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kitchen) and [kitchens](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kitchens) in the available tags. I'm pretty sure they mean the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tags are already synonyms.

I have now merged them.

The tag is now [kitchens](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kitchens)